# Rails 3: How can I find rows in a table that were created today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Preferably I'd like to use a statement like...

`current_user.workouts.find_by_created_at(Time.now.day)`

but that doesn't work, I'm guessing because the times don't match up.  I'm going to keep reading through the docs, but I thought I'd post this question to seek help while I'm reading.

Thanks!

***UPDATE***
Using the new Rails 3 support for ARel and named scopes, I refactored the query to...

Model

```
   class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
      scope :from_today, where(" created_at between ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
    .
    .
    .
    end
```

Controller

```
def create
  workouts = current_user.workouts.from_today
.
.
.
end
```

Comment: watch out for scopes.  in rails 2 scopes had issues, you may need to do the following:  where(" created_at between #{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day} AND #{Time.zone.now.end_of_day}")  otherwise the date is cached when the server starts. "?" syntax was cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
current_user.workouts.find(:all, :conditions => [" YEAR(created_at) = ? AND MONTH(created_at) = ? AND DAY(created_at) = ?", Time.zone.now.year, Time.zone.now.month, Time.zone.now.day])
```

or

```
current_user.workouts.find(:all, :conditions => [" created_at between ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day])
```

not sure which is more optimized

Comment: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day is preferred.  Time.zone.now.day will be UTC which will return the right date but on MYSQL you might have all dates stored UTC.  Thus giving you the wrong results.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MySQL you can do the following:

Rails 3:

```
current_user.workouts.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.today)
```

Rails 2:

```
current_user.workouts.find(:all, :conditions => ['DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.today])
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a gem for this kind of operation, it's called [`by_star`](http://github.com/radar/by_star). With it, you could do this to get all records created today:

```
current_user.workouts.today
```

There's plenty of other helpful methods too. Give it a go.